# How to open new rows based on 2 date columns in r

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, lubridate

I have the following sample dataset of a large dataset -

```
     isin       directorid dob_Year2 ROLE_START ROLE_END gender datestartrole dateendrole
 US6819771048     340769      1970       1995     2003      M    1995-02-01  2003-01-09
 US6819771048     340769      1970       2003     2004      M    2003-01-09  2004-02-24
 US6819771048     340769      1970       2004     2007      M    2004-02-24  2007-09-07
 US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30
 US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1976     1986      M    1976-04-01  1986-01-01
 US68243Q1067     327069      1961       2016     2020      M    2016-06-30  2020-05-21
```

My **QUESTION** is - 
I want to create **New Rows** based on the variables `ROLE_START` and `ROLE_END`. The number of 
rows to be created depends the **MINIMUM** `ROLE_START` and **MAXIMUM** `ROLE_END` assuming that the data is grouped by `isin` and `directorid`. For example - for `isin` US6819771048 and `directorid` 340769, the **MINIMUM** `ROLE_START` year is 1995 and **MAXIMUM** `ROLE_END` year is 2007. So I need to open rows for each year of 1995-2007 and theses years should be stored in `YEAR` variable. **Please note that in the above example there is no break between 1995-2007 because it is clear from `ROLE_START` and `ROLE_END` that all years are included. If there is any break between any years, then those breaks should be excluded**. For the above sample dataset, my expected dataset should be look like this -

```
     isin       directorid dob_Year2 ROLE_START ROLE_END gender datestartrole dateendrole YEAR
US6819771048     340769      1970       1995     2003      M    1995-02-01  2003-01-09   1995
US6819771048     340769      1970       1995     2003      M    1995-02-01  2003-01-09   1996
US6819771048     340769      1970       1995     2003      M    1995-02-01  2003-01-09   1997
US6819771048     340769      1970       1995     2003      M    1995-02-01  2003-01-09   1998
US6819771048     340769      1970       1995     2003      M    1995-02-01  2003-01-09   1999
US6819771048     340769      1970       1995     2003      M    1995-02-01  2003-01-09   2000
US6819771048     340769      1970       1995     2003      M    1995-02-01  2003-01-09   2001
US6819771048     340769      1970       1995     2003      M    1995-02-01  2003-01-09   2002
US6819771048     340769      1970       1995     2003      M    1995-02-01  2003-01-09   2003
US6819771048     340769      1970       2003     2004      M    2003-01-09  2004-02-24   2003
US6819771048     340769      1970       2003     2004      M    2003-01-09  2004-02-24   2004
US6819771048     340769      1970       2004     2007      M    2004-02-24  2007-09-07   2004
US6819771048     340769      1970       2004     2007      M    2004-02-24  2007-09-07   2005
US6819771048     340769      1970       2004     2007      M    2004-02-24  2007-09-07   2006
US6819771048     340769      1970       2004     2007      M    2004-02-24  2007-09-07   2007
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   1986
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   1987
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   1988
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   1989
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   1990
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   1991
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   1992
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   1993
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   1994
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   1995
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   1996
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   1997
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   1998
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   1999
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   2000
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   2001
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   2002
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   2003
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   2004
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   2005
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   2006
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   2007
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   2008
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   2009
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   2010
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   2011
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   2012
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   2013
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   2014
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   2015
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1986     2016      M    1986-01-01  2016-06-30   2016
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1976     1986      M    1976-04-01  1986-01-01   1976
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1976     1986      M    1976-04-01  1986-01-01   1977
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1976     1986      M    1976-04-01  1986-01-01   1978
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1976     1986      M    1976-04-01  1986-01-01   1979
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1976     1986      M    1976-04-01  1986-01-01   1980
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1976     1986      M    1976-04-01  1986-01-01   1981
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1976     1986      M    1976-04-01  1986-01-01   1982
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1976     1986      M    1976-04-01  1986-01-01   1983
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1976     1986      M    1976-04-01  1986-01-01   1984
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1976     1986      M    1976-04-01  1986-01-01   1985
US68243Q1067      86917      1951       1976     1986      M    1976-04-01  1986-01-01   1986
US68243Q1067     327069      1961       2016     2020      M    2016-06-30  2020-05-21   2016
US68243Q1067     327069      1961       2016     2020      M    2016-06-30  2020-05-21   2017
US68243Q1067     327069      1961       2016     2020      M    2016-06-30  2020-05-21   2018
US68243Q1067     327069      1961       2016     2020      M    2016-06-30  2020-05-21   2019
US68243Q1067     327069      1961       2016     2020      M    2016-06-30  2020-05-21   2020
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a sequence between `ROLE_START` and `ROLE_END` and get data in different rows.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(YEAR = purrr::map2(ROLE_START, ROLE_END, seq)) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(YEAR)


#   isin         directorid dob_Year2 ROLE_START ROLE_END gender datestartrole dateendrole  YEAR
#   <chr>             <int>     <int>      <int>    <int> <chr>  <chr>         <chr>       <int>
# 1 US6819771048     340769      1970       1995     2003 M      1995-02-01    2003-01-09   1995
# 2 US6819771048     340769      1970       1995     2003 M      1995-02-01    2003-01-09   1996
# 3 US6819771048     340769      1970       1995     2003 M      1995-02-01    2003-01-09   1997
# 4 US6819771048     340769      1970       1995     2003 M      1995-02-01    2003-01-09   1998
# 5 US6819771048     340769      1970       1995     2003 M      1995-02-01    2003-01-09   1999
# 6 US6819771048     340769      1970       1995     2003 M      1995-02-01    2003-01-09   2000
# 7 US6819771048     340769      1970       1995     2003 M      1995-02-01    2003-01-09   2001
# 8 US6819771048     340769      1970       1995     2003 M      1995-02-01    2003-01-09   2002
# 9 US6819771048     340769      1970       1995     2003 M      1995-02-01    2003-01-09   2003
#10 US6819771048     340769      1970       2003     2004 M      2003-01-09    2004-02-24   2003
# … with 52 more rows
```

Comment: Hi, @Ronak Shah- I get error message when I apply the above code in the larger dataset. The error message is - ```Error in seq.default(.x[[1L]], .y[[1L]], ...) : 
  'from' must be a finite number``` Another question - I think I should use ```group_by(isin, directorid)``` before I use the above code?

Comment: I don't think `group_by` is needed because if I have understood correctly you want to expand the rows based on `ROLE_START` and `ROLE_END` irrespective of which group they belong. As far as error message is concerned do you `NA` values in the data? If yes, what would you like to do for it?

Comment: Hi, @Ronak Shah- I have ```NA``` I believe. I am OK if they are taken out. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, @Ronak Shah- it works now if I take out the ```NA```. Thanks.